# Flutter GetX controller getting null instead of data

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-state, flutter-get

I have an API (which does work and returns a response, and I even can see the response 1 line above the `return` statement), but for some reason, when the data should be passed to the variable, I receive null, instead of the returned value.

**the service DOES return data** **I DO get the value from the API**, at least it shows that there is data in the variable before the return.

The **resp** variable, which should contain the data, shows that the value is empty.

**api_service.dart** <= Returns a value

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class RemoteServices {
  static var client = http.Client();

  static Future sendImageForAnalysis(String filename) async {
    var request =
        http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse("http://10.0.2.2:8000/api"));

    request.files.add(http.MultipartFile('picture',
        File(filename).readAsBytes().asStream(), File(filename).lengthSync(),
        filename: filename.split("/").last));

    var res = await request.send();
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      http.Response.fromStream(res)
          .then((response) {
            var dataAsJson = json.decode(response.body);
            /* The variable from above does have data, it's not empty and none of the errors appears*/
            return dataAsJson;
          })
          .catchError((error) => print('Something went wrong')) /* Error is not showing */
          .whenComplete(() => print('Got data from the server'));
    } else {
      /* Code does not get here */
      return {'name': 'x'};
    }
  }
}
```

**controller_results.dart** <= Shows null, instead of the value.

```
import 'package:face_search/services/api_service.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class ResultsController extends GetxController {
  final data = {}.obs;
  final name = ''.obs;

  void getItemData(imagePath) async {
    var resp = await RemoteServices.sendImageForAnalysis(imagePath);
    print(resp); /* This is empty for some reason */
    if (resp != null) {
      data.value = resp;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `return` before `http.Response.fromStream(res)`.

Answer (score 0):

Does the result of the api return json? If its return json why dont try to create a model for it and call the list on your controller so that you can freely know if its having a data to return.

Comment: Yes, I do get data from the API, but I'm building the API by myself, so for now it just returns {'title": "hello}, and I do get it a line before i return, but when it's going back to the controller, I get null, instead of that data.